# Clatherin Mediated endocytosis is pinocytosis or phagocytosis?

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology

This was a question in a test. Clatherin mediated endocytosis is which of the two: pinocytosis or phagocytosis?

Precisely what is the difference between the two and CME?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer would be pinocytosis
Eukaryotic cells are also able to take up macromolecules and particles from the surrounding medium by a distinct process called endocytosis. In endocytosis, the material to be internalized is surrounded by an area of the plasma membrane, which then buds off inside the cell to form a vesicle containing the ingested material. The term “endocytosis” was coined by Christian de Duve in 1963 to include both the ingestion of large particles (such as bacteria) and the uptake of fluids or macromolecules in small vesicles. The former of these activities is known as phagocytosis (cell eating) and the latter as pinocytosis (cell drinking).

During phagocytosis, cells engulf large particles such as bacteria, cell debris, or even intact cells.In contrast to phagocytosis, which plays only specialized roles, pinocytosis is common among eukaryotic cells. The best-characterized form of this process is receptor-mediated endocytosis, which provides a mechanism for the selective uptake of specific macromolecules.The macromolecules to be internalized the first bind to specific cell surface receptors. These receptors are concentrated in specialized regions of the plasma membrane, called clathrin-coated pits. These pits bud from the membrane to form small clathrin-coated vesicles containing the receptors and their bound macromolecules (ligands). The clathrin-coated vesicles then fuse with early endosomes, in which their contents are sorted for transport to lysosomes or recycling to the plasma membrane.

For more information please see this link https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK9831/

Hope this helps!